# TKinter: Imprimir etiqueta en un tabulador a través de un botón

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy teniendo un pequeño problema al intentar copiar el directorio como etiqueta en un tabulador al presionar un botón en TKinter.
Cuando corro el programa, se me genera la ventana con el tabulador, en el tabulador he puesto un botón que al ser presionado me permite ubicar un directorio el cuál lo almaceno en una variable. Lo que quisiera es que cuando aprieto el botón, y localizo el directorio, me gustaría imprimir en una etiqueta en el tabulador, la dirección de ese directorio, ya que cuando presiono el botón y elijo el directorio, el programa deja de funcionar porque no es capaz de copiar en la etiqueta del tabulador la dirección almacenada.
si me pudieran ayudar les estaría muy agradecido.
A continuación le comparto el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Zeuz(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('950x500')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.title('ZEUZ-THB')
        self.iconbitmap('rayo.ico')

        # Crear la etiqueta que muestra la ruta del directorio seleccionado
        self.dir_path_label = ttk.Label(self, text='')

        # Método que contiene los tabs
        self._crear_tabs()

    def _tab_1(self, tab_1):
        def select_path_serv():
            # Abrir el cuadro de diálogo de selección de directorio
            dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

            # Actualizar la etiqueta que muestra la ruta del directorio seleccionado
            self.dir_path_label.config(text=dir_path)
            self.dir_path_label.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        boton1 = ttk.Button(tab_1, text='Servidor', command=select_path_serv)
        boton1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

    def _crear_tabs(self):
        control_tab = ttk.Notebook(self)
        tab_1 = ttk.Frame(control_tab)
        control_tab.add(tab_1, text='Información')
        control_tab.pack(fill='both')

        self._tab_1(tab_1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    thb = Zeuz()
    thb.mainloop()
```